Pouchdb putattachment promise is not being resolved
Pouchdb putAttachment is not returning promise. attachments are not being saved in couchdb
trying to put blob attachment in pouchdb version (7) but the db.putAttachment(.....) not getting resolved.
attachment is not being saved in couchdb
        this._db
            .putAttachment(docId, attachmentId, rev, attachment, type)
            .then(data => {
                observer.next(data);
                observer.complete();
            })
            .catch(err => {
                observer.error(err);
                observer.complete();
            });

This putAttachment promise is not getting resolved also not getting rejected , not getting any error

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
